# Installed Intel C++ Compiler, missing /bits/c++config

Tags: c++, gcc, icc

I installed the intel c++ compiler, and sourced the compilervars.h file. (I think this is how you are supposed to set up the compiler).

When testing a simple HelloWorld! program compiling with the icpc command for bot the .cpp and .o files I am told that there is no /bits/c++config.h file. The file is not located under /usr/include/c++/4.8/bits or /usr/include/c++/4.8.1/bits. I have read up on this problem (there were a few threads about it) but could not figure out how to fix it.

I got the program to compile by using gcc for the .cpp file and icpc for the .o file. gcc won't compile the .o file and icpc won't compile the .cpp file.

I am a rookie to setting up programming environments because I mostly have just programmed via shh on school computers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you can try using "g++ -v" to compile and find out all the include directories. "-v" should be also OK for ICC, and you can then compare what the difference is.

Comment: @YongweiWu "-v" list some directories, which I looked in. Not sure what I am supposed to be doing with this information though.

Comment: It might be that ICC does not support your specific GCC version well. If you see a GCC directory that is missing in the "icpc -v" output, try using -I to add it to the icpc command line.

Answer (score 0):

This shall be fixed by adding corresponding -I option to your compiling command. If your machine is x32, try something like

```
-I/usr/include/i386-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/
```

or

```
-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/
```

for x64 machine.

Comment: I tried "-I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/" (for 64bit) and got this in return "bash: -I/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/4.8/: No such file or directory".

Comment: which OS do you use? cd to /usr/include and see if you have anything similar